# How to fixing ion-radio-group cant selected from array

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

im going to auto check in radiobutton but is cant be selected

im try a radiobutton disable and this work but checked is doesnt work

in page.html

```html
<div *ngIf="soal?.kind == 2">
      <ion-radio-group [(ngModel)]="jawaban">
        <ion-item *ngFor="let cat of answer">
          <ion-label>{{cat.text}}</ion-label>
          <ion-radio *ngIf="cat?.checked" slot="end" value="{{cat.key}}" checked></ion-radio>
          <ion-radio *ngIf="!cat?.checked" slot="end" value="{{cat.key}}"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-radio-group>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## .html

```
<div *ngIf="soal?.kind == 2">
      <ion-radio-group [(ngModel)]="jawaban">
        <ion-item *ngFor="let cat of answer">
          <ion-label>{{cat.text}}</ion-label>
          <ion-radio [attr.checked]="value === 'black' ? 'checked' : null"  slot="end" value="{{cat.key}}" ></ion-radio>
          <ion-radio [attr.checked]="value === 'brown' ? 'checked' : null" slot="end" value="{{cat.key}}"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-radio-group>
    </div>
```

## .ts

```
value = 'brown';
```